# Why is there no local min for this graph?

Tags: calculus

> Graph of $f'(x)$

[image]

Supposedly there is no local minimum on the interval (0, 8) for the above graph, but I don't understand why. I thought there were local mins at x = 1 and x = 6.

Comment: The function being graphed has local minima, but your link suggests that this is the graph of the derivative of the function you are inspecting?

Comment: You have the graph of $f'(x)$, while I suspect that the question asks about the minima of $f(x)$. Can that be right?

Comment: Oh! It is asking for the minima of f(x). Is the minima of f(x) where f'(x) is above 0?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the exercise is asking you to explain that there are no local minima of $f$, providing you with the graph of $f'$. If this interpretation of the exercise is correct, consider that candidates for local extrema of $f$ are at zeros of $f'$. There is one zero of $f'$ in the middle of the picture, but no sign change in $f'$ occurs there, so this is not a local extremum. (Near this point the graph would look something like the graph of $y=-x^3$ near $x=0$.)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this is the graph of the derivative of f(x).  Does your teacher mean to find local max/mins for the original function?  If so, f(x) would have no local min because notice the slope (f'(x)) is always zero except at x=4 which indicates an inflection point.

Comment: Not of the function $f$.

Comment: The link to the graph says **"Graph of f'(x)".**  So, yeah, it was stated in the question, Tye.

Comment: Since the OP has been told that whatever function is under consideration has no local minimum in $(0,8)$, and since we’re clearly given the graph of $f'$, not of $f$, it is easily inferred from the available information that the original question was almost certainly about $f$, not about $f'$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you are correct.  I did not notice the ' on the link f'(x).  Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome; sorry if I sounded a bit abrupt.